# @media screen: Viewport or Window size?

Tags: css

Good Day

I am getting somewhat confused, probably cause I haven't used media queries in a while:

when using

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px){

}
```

does it refer to the **Viewport size**(viewable part of the page) or the **Window Size**(including scrollbars etc) ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [media query max-width relates to the view port size or the windows size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182201/media-query-max-width-relates-to-the-view-port-size-or-the-windows-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It refers to the width of the viewport:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width

[media query max-width relates to the view port size or the windows size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13182201/media-query-max-width-relates-to-the-view-port-size-or-the-windows-size)

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen

html{
width: 1024px;
}
```

That may help you.